# What is the space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in relation to a Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, soft-question, banach-spaces

A Banach space is a complete, normed, vector space.

What is the set of vectors $\mathbb{R}^n$ in terms of a Banach space?

Meaning, is $\mathbb{R}^n$ a Banach space? If so, is it a specific type of Banach space? If not, what assumptions can be added to make $\mathbb{R}^n$ a Banach space?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the vector space $\Bbb{R}^n$ (over $\Bbb{R}$) into a Banach space, you'll need to equip $\Bbb{R}^n$ with a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition). That is, a map
$$\| \cdot \| : \Bbb{R}^n \to [0, \infty)$$
such that, for all $x, y \in \Bbb{R}^n$, and $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$,

1. $\|x\| = 0 \implies x = 0$,
2. $\|\lambda x\| = |\lambda| \|x\|$,
3. $\|x + y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\|$.

Typically one equips the Euclidean norm:
$$\|(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2},$$
but there is an enormous variety of possible norms to equip to $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Banach spaces need to be complete, in the sense that Cauchy sequences must converge. Fortunately, every norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$ will make the space complete. (This is not true for infinite-dimensional spaces!)

Answer (score 1):

To be a Banach space the vector space must be equipped with a norm. When you speak of $\mathbb R^n$ you only have a vector space. So, no it is not a Banach space. To obtain a Banach space you must specify a complete norm. It is a theorem that in a finite dimensional vector space, any norm will be complete. So, to obtain a Banach space structure on $\mathbb R^n$ all you have to do is choose a norm. There are plenty of norms, in fact infinitely many, to choose from. I won't list any here but just mention that in fact once you have a norm you can look at the unit ball in that norm. You'll get a non-empty, bounded, closed, convex, and star-like subset of $\mathbb R^n$. It is not hard to show that given any such subset there is a unique norm giving it as its unit ball. So, you can tailor a norm nearly as freely as you'd like.

Comment: So is the pair $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|)$ a specific type of Banach space? I am trying to understand how functional analysis people categorize/characterize $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|)$. A parallel example in topology would be to say that $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology is a second countable Hausdorff space.

Comment: no, not a specific type of Banach space but rather simply a Banach space. Once you specified a vector space and a complete norm on it then you've specified a Banach space.

Comment: @Themanofyourdream The usual euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^n$ is special because it comes from an inner product, and under this inner product (the usual dot product), $\mathbb R^n$ is not only a Banach space but also a Hilbert space, which has many nice properties that a general Banach space need not have.